# При запуске программы не отображаются все свойства экземпляра класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, атрибуты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы отображались при команде `print` все свойства экземпляра `pt`? 
Я просто не совсем понимаю, ведь все свойства класса `PersonalComputers()` наследуются экземпляром класса `pt` или нет? 
Команда `pt.__dict__` отображает их все, но на печати только два из дочернего класса `Table()`.
Заранее огромное спасибо!

```
class PersonalComputers:
    def __init__(self, ram: int = 32, hdd: int = 1024, model: str = 'Pentium', cpu: int = 3):
        self._ram = ram
        self._hdd = hdd
        self._model = model
        self._cpu = cpu


class Table(PersonalComputers):
    def __init__(self, keyboard, mouse, display):
        self.__keyboard = keyboard
        self.__mouse = mouse
        self.__display = display
        super(Table, self).__init__(keyboard, mouse, display)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__keyboard},{self.__mouse},{self.__display}'


class LapTops(PersonalComputers):
    def __init__(self, diagonal, size):
        self.__diagonal = diagonal
        self.__size = size
        super(LapTops, self).__init__(diagonal, size)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__diagonal},{self.__size}'


pt = LapTops(10, 15)
print(pt)  # 10, 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `Table` вообще никак не задействован.

Класс `LapTops` наследуется от `PersonalComputers`
и при инициализации вы наследуете все его атрибуты.

При этом вы передаете в класс `PersonalComputers` два параметра,
которые принимаются аргументами `ram` и `hdd` и меняют свои значения.

Чтобы отображались все атрибуты класса `LapTops`,
в т.ч. и наследованные - добавьте их в `return` метода `__str__`

```
class PersonalComputers:
    def __init__(self, ram: int = 32, hdd: int = 1024, model: str = 'Pentium', cpu: int = 3):
        self._ram = ram
        self._hdd = hdd
        self._model = model
        self._cpu = cpu
        print(f'\nclass PersonalComputers: {ram}, {hdd}, {model}, {cpu}\n')

class Table(PersonalComputers):
    def __init__(self, keyboard, mouse, display):
        self.__keyboard = keyboard
        self.__mouse = mouse
        self.__display = display
        super(Table, self).__init__(keyboard, mouse, display)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'\n ???? Table: {self.__keyboard}, {self.__mouse},{self.__display}'


class LapTops(PersonalComputers):
    def __init__(self, diagonal, size):
        self.__diagonal = diagonal
        self.__size = size
        super(LapTops, self).__init__(diagonal, size)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'LapTops: {self.__diagonal}, {self.__size}\n' \
               f'\tram: {self._ram}, hdd: {self._hdd}, model: {self._model}, cpu: {self._cpu}'


pt = LapTops(10, 15)
print(pt)
```

Comment: @s-nick большое спасибо! А вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, подсказать, как сделать так, что бы менялись diagonal и size? Когда я ввожу LapTops(10, 15) меняются как раз, как вы правильно заметили ram и hdd. А если не вводить ничего, то интерпретатор логично выдаёт ошибку о нехватке аргументов.

Comment: @TobaSko  не уверен что правильно понял ваш вопрос, но попробуйте заменить строку `super(LapTops, self).__init__(diagonal, size)`  на `super(LapTops, self).__init__(ram=12, hdd=516, model='Hello World')` .